# To filter data in table using a Access form and selecting a value in combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vba6

I'm working on Access Tracker, basically it has a table and form. The column headers of table are parent entity, subs, Compliance etc., the combo boxes in form are parententity2, subs2, compliance2, etc. Each parent in the table can have multiple subs. I have written a code in such a way when I select a value in the form of parententity2, then it autopopulates the rest of the information. However, when a parent has multiple subs it is not showing all of the values, instead it is showing the first value which is in the list. For example ABC is a parent company and A1, B1, C1, are subs..then output is when I filter ABC then under subs dropdown I can only see A1, instead of A1, B1, C1

```
Private Sub Subs2_AfterUpdate()

Dim strFilter As String

Dim abc


    ' Get the selected value from the parententity2 combo box
    'Dim strFilter As String
    strFilter = Me.Parententity2.Value
    
    ' Apply the filter to the form's record source
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM [Data] WHERE [parent entity] = '" & strFilter & "'"
    
    ' Populate the Subs column with the filtered data
    Me.Subs2.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [subs] FROM [Data] WHERE [parent entity] = '" & strFilter & "'"
End sub
```

Comment: Looks like code should work. However, why are you pulling subs from Data table and not a lookup table? Are you sure there are records in Data with all 3 sub values? Edit question to show sample data as formatted text tables.

Comment: Yes, for few accounts there is only on sub and for few more than 2... Data is the name of the table here

Comment: Just to add for above questions the columns I have selected are in short text format and their look up property is text box , is this can be a reason..I tried changing to combo box, when I changed it the output whatever I was getting even that is not populating

Comment: Maybe post in a forum that allows attaching files and post your db for analysis.

Comment: Im not sure which forum it is, since am working in a company I cannot attach files to outside company portals

Comment: Would love to help if I had enough information to work with. Don't know your data structure nor form design. That's a big vacuum. As I said, code presented looks like it should work.

Comment: Can I know your email id, or how can we both connect?

Comment: Sorry, no. Only communication is via forum.

Comment: I didnt understand by the word forum...can you share the link of that forum

Comment: Stackoverflow is a forum. Communicate via these comments or answer here or in any other website forum.

Comment: I can let you know all the details which you need......All the boxes in userform are selected as combo box... the data types of table are selected as short text and the look up as text box...row source for parent entity is SELECT Data.ID, Data.[Parent entity] FROM Data; ...and there is no row source for other combo boxes....

Comment: let me know if you need any further information

Comment: I also tried changing the look up of data types to combo box and making the value as yes for allow multiple entries..but this didnt work

Comment: That doesn't really provide any new info, except "no row source for other combo boxes" which makes no sense. I already advised what I would need to analyze this issue.

Comment: Can we attach the file here?

Comment: All info to analyze issue is supposed to be within the question, not linked files or downloads. No, files cannot be directly attached. You can post a link to a download but many will not download from external sources. I already suggested posting in a forum that does allow attaching files and you said you cannot attach files.